# How do I rename bundles generated with Angular 7?

Tags: angular

I've created a new Angular 7 project and it builds bundles with the names `runtime.js`, `main.js`, `polyfills.js`, `styles.js`. **How can I configure my project to build bundles with custom names?**

I'm working with a complex project that has multiple angular apps (version 4.x) running on the page at the same time. I have separate app (also Angular v.4.x) that  handles config for loading bundles of all other apps. List of bundles are hardcoded and this is something that I cannot change. Therefore, when I want my Angular 7 app to be bootstrapped by this code, I cannot do this on production, because names of bundles don't match.

I failed to configure project at this point, because, as far as I could find, webpack config is hidden from developer. I think of writing kind of post build script that will be done after bundles are created and will simply rename files, but such workaround seems to be slightly risky and I don't know if it's actually feasible solution.

My build script:

`"release": "ng build --prod --aot --extract-css=false --output-hashing=none --source-map=true"`.

This is the list of bundle names that are loaded per each Angular v.4.x app and I need to have the same from Angular v.7.x:

```
'main.bundle.js':,
'vendor.bundle.js',
'styles.bundle.js',
'inline.bundle.js',
'scripts.bundle.js',
'polyfills.bundle.js'.
```

This is the list of bundles I get from Angular v.7.x app:

```
'runtime.js',
'main.js', 
'polyfills.js',
'styles.js'
```

Comment: By default those bundle names in angular v7 (and earlier too) usually include a hash in the name for cache busting. Are you not getting that or did you turn that off? Or maybe you are not building with the production flag?

Comment: Also all the configuration should be available in `angular.json` although it looks like not every output name is configurable. Maybe you can run a custom script post execution to rename the files and then include a couple of empty ones for the files that are no longer included in the build in v7.

Comment: Hi, @Igor!
Thank you for the comment. Yes, I have `--output-hashing=none` in build script. I will check out more about `angular.json` settings, probably, will find some solution there.

Comment: Seriously, multiple angular apps on one page? I think filenames are the least of your worries.. (zone errors!!)

Comment: @MikeOne, nah, we are fine with this issue, already tested. Pretty last thing left is only bundle naming...

Answer (score 3):

You can use Angular Builders to customize any part of the build. You can configure filenames using the webpack builder:

**angular.json**

```
"architect": {
  "build": {
    "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
    "options": {
      "customWebpackConfig": {
        "path": "./webpack.config.js",
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: false
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].[hash].min.js'
  }
}
```

Then running the normal angular build (which will use the angular.json configuration):

```
ng build --prod
```

Comment: `Property 'customWebpackConfig' is not allowed` - this doesn't seem correct?

Comment: This was for Angular v7, Angular is now at v12 so this approach might not work now

Comment: Thanks, yeah apparently not on v11 (what we're on)

Comment: It worked for us on Angular 13. I did not need the `runtimeChunk` flag

Answer (score 2):

Check your `angular.json` file in the `configurations` section you should have `outputHashing` set to `true` in the configuration you are using. These options are also available from the CLI.

For reference: [ng build](https://angular.io/cli/build)

### Update:

In latest Angular versions, the possible values of `outputHashing` are `none|all|media|bundles` instead of `boolean`. For a total cache busting or name isolation between two builds, use `all`.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the comment! Not sure if I need this, I'd like to avoid having hash in filename, I just need totally different filenames :)

Comment: Why? The hashes are guaranteed to be different between your two apps, why would you use your own filenames?

Comment: Imagine having localized builds that are served based on a language cookie. The scripts in the builds all have the same filename, including `main.[hash].js` which holds all the translations. The browser caches this. So when you change the language in the client, the back-end serves `main.[hash].js` from the selected language, but the browser will still use the cached script from the previous language. Adding the locale to the filename would solve this, for instance `fr.main.[hash].js`.